# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Uri'

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I have been working on a flutter mobile project of a taxi clone app. I have used Google Maps API for GeoCoding and Directions. I have been following a tutorial on youtube ([the link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hiT9tlWipE&list=PLxefhmF0pcPlJxSaSFTX-066606EpCpav&index=18)). When I run the project I don't get any data and see this error in the console

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type
> 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Uri'

Please help me. I am doing it for a school project

Comment: It's mostly likely due to the versioning of the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http/example). Are you using the latest version of that package?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's most likely due to the versioning of the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http). Looking at the video tutorial, it appears that the teacher used http 0.12.2, while it seems that you are using a later version(0.13.0 or above). If you look at the [changelog](http://%20https://pub.dev/packages/http/changelog), you'd see this note on the changes made after 0.12.2:

> **Breaking** All APIs which previously allowed a String or Uri to be
> passed now require a Uri.

To solve your issue, you need to pass a Uri instead of a String

```
var url = Uri.parse('https://example.com');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are life saver

Answer (score 1):

You probably used a String ("https://yoursuperendpoint.com" for exemple)
And you need to use a URI: there is a special `Uri` class for this.

You have the documentation there: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri-class.html

But you probably will use the [`Uri.tryParse()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/tryParse.html) method.